# Get All Changes of Any registered model of a single user django-simple-history

Tags: django, django-simple-history

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'simple_history',
    # ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models

from apps.companies.models import Company
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    history = HistoricalRecords()


class Contact(TimeStamp):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Person Name')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Personal Number', null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Personal Email')
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`user = User.objects.first()`
is there anyway to get all changes any model by the `user`

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems similar than this issue on the `django-simple-history` repository : https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/issues/684

> You'd have to query each historical model since they're all in
> separate tables. You could build a way to automatically detect which
> models are historical and get them though.